Redirecting an app's camera access
I'd like to use an external camera for video calls.
Connecting the camera via USB works, and the camera reports going from "standby" to "output" mode when I open the app, but the app seems to be hardcoded to the standard "front"/"back" cameras.
Is there a way to configure "if an app asks for the front camera, use this external camera instead"?

TLDR:
Sadly no.

Apps using Android framework camera API are limited to what the OS allows.
Android Open Source Project (AOSP) does allow for building with external USB Webcam (UVC device) support so devices like set-top boxes / Android TVs are more likely to have them enabled.
Typically phones and tablets have their own front and rear facing cameras so don't have UVC support built into the OS and apps which want to use UVC will require driver/library code for support.
Custom ROMs may if implemented allow for UVC support/configuration through framework.

Detail:
Android OS is developed for specific hardware. Support for additional hardware will need to be baked in. For consumer devices with Google Play Services they need to follow the Android Compatibility Definition Document for the OS version of particular device's release.
So for a device released with Android 15 which states in the Android 15 CDD Section 7.5.3. External Camera:

MAY include support for an external camera that is not necessarily always connected.

As seen in: https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camera2/camera-enumeration app developers can use existing Android APIs to see if an CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL is available.
If the Android framework doesn't support an external camera, it would be up to the Android app developer to include support.
Be aware that Linux's UVC driver doesn't support all media payloads and UVC hardware have implementation issues so not all webcams are the same.

I'm sure the actual connectivity works (the camera has an integrated display, and shows the status change when the app is opened -- so the camera framework even starts streaming data), so all that is left to do is "use this device instead of the other one".

Even if the framework detects the EXTERNAL_CAMERA but that still means the app has to use that API as well, which is a code change. You may want to identify the app specifically and check to see if there are any settings within in the app to handle the UVC. Note that the camera sending data doesn't mean the receiver device is actually listening.

Hence the question if I can redirect this at system level, like I can for example redirect the location API to a fake location provider.

While you can use a fake location provider (note app can detect), no such feature is available in stock AOSP, see the many questions on SO regarding Android and USB Camera. At a guess why its a 'MAY' support is that phones/tablets already have a built-in camera so additional ODM testing isn't required / perhaps to make biometric w/camera easier. With rumors of desktop coming to Android perhaps this might change but as of now in 2024 supporting ext USB camera would require Android device and Android app support.
